# How to get loop to stop

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I need help or some ideas on how to get the loop in this code to stop executing when the speedUp factor settles to a particular value. The idea of this method is continually run an ever increasing number of threads and derive a speedUp factor from the results. The rounded speedUp factor is how many cores are present on the machine. Running a 4 threaded task will have the same speedUp factor as a 16 threaded task on a 4 core machine. I want to be able to not have to manually set number of threads to run. When the speedUp factor settles to a value I want the program to terminate. There is no need to run a test for 8, 16, or 32 threads if the speed up factor has already settled at 2 for example.

Example output for a 4 core machine:

Number of threads tested: 1
Speed up factor: 1.0

Number of threads tested: 2
Speed up factor: 1.8473736372646188

Number of threads tested: 4
Speed up factor: 3.9416666666666669

Number of threads tested: 8
Speed up factor: 3.9750993377483446

Number of threads tested: 16
Speed up factor: 4.026086956521739

THIS MACHINE HAS: 4 CORES

THE APPLICATION HAS COMPLETED EXECUTION. THANK YOU

```html
private static void multiCoreTest() {
  // A runnable for the threads
  Counter task = new Counter(1500000000L);
  
  // A variable to store the number of threads to run
  int threadMultiplier = 1;
  
  // A variable to hold the time it takes for a single thread to execute
  double singleThreadTime = ThreadTest.runTime(1, task);

  // Calculating speedup factor for a single thread task
  double speedUp = (singleThreadTime * threadMultiplier) / (singleThreadTime);
 
  // Printing the speed up factor of a single thread
  System.out.println("Number of threads tested: " + threadMultiplier);
  System.out.println("Speed up factor: " + speedUp);

  // Testing multiple threads
  while (threadMultiplier < 16) {

   // Increasing the number of threads by a factor of two
   threadMultiplier *= 2;

   // A variable to hold the time it takes for multiple threads to
   // execute
   double multiThreadTime = ThreadTest.runTime(threadMultiplier, task);

   // Calculating speedup factor for multiple thread tests
   speedUp = (singleThreadTime * threadMultiplier) / (multiThreadTime);

   // Message to the user
   System.out.println("\n" + "Number of threads tested: "
     + threadMultiplier);
   System.out.println("Speed up factor: " + speedUp);

  }
  // Print number of cores
  System.out.println("\n" + "THIS MACHINE HAS: " + Math.round(speedUp)
    + " CORES");
  System.out.println("\n"
    + "THE APPLICATION HAS COMPLETED EXECUTION. THANK YOU");
  // Exiting the system
  System.exit(0);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the new speedup is the same as the old one:

```
double oldSpeedUp = 0;
boolean found = false;
while(!found && threadMultiplier < 16) {
    // ...
    found = Math.round(speedUp) == Math.round(oldSpeedUp);
    oldSpeedUp = speedUp;
}
```

As a side note, if you want the number of cores, you can call :

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! Yeah I know that's the easy way to find cores haha. My parallel in instructor want's us to write a program that does it another way.

Comment: BTW The `availableProcessors` is the number of logical CPU in the machine, but not the number of cores if you have hyperthreading and if use us affinity or the machine is busy, you will get very different results.